# OpenSSL undefined references

Tags: c, openssl

I'm new to OpenSSL and I'm trying to compile [this example](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_md5.html) I found in their docs. The example verbatim is as follows:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <openssl/evp.h>

 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 EVP_MD_CTX *mdctx;
 const EVP_MD *md;
 char mess1[] = "Test Message\n";
 char mess2[] = "Hello World\n";
 unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
 int md_len, i;

 if (argv[1] == NULL) {
        printf("Usage: mdtest digestname\n");
        exit(1);
 }

 md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);
 if (md == NULL) {
        printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
 }

 mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
 EVP_DigestInit_ex(mdctx, md, NULL);
 EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
 EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
 EVP_DigestFinal_ex(mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
 EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);

 printf("Digest is: ");
 for (i = 0; i < md_len; i++)
        printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
 printf("\n");

 exit(0);
 }
```

Which I then try to compile with:

```
gcc example.c -lssl -lcrypto
```

And I get the following output:

```
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:25:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
       ^
example.c:27:32: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
 EVP_DigestUpdate(mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
                                ^
/tmp/ccWb0D5B.o: In function `main':
example.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
example.c:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So what libraries am I missing? I've spent some time searching for this but all the answers I've seen are just variations of just using `-lssl -lcrypto`. Thanks.

Comment: The most obvious #include you're missing is string.h, as strlen isn't supported without it. That will squelch at least one of your warnings. And I think you may need the create/destroy api, not the new/free version. Check your API.

Comment: What _OpenSSL_ version are you using? I only saw `EVP_MD_CTX_new` in v1.1.0 include files.

Comment: @CristiFati It was a versioning problem indeed. I solved it by compiling from source. See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@john !

A wild guess would be that you have installed in your computer a version of OpenSSL library and include files that is incompatible to your current OpenSSL library and include files.

The warning

```
example.c:25:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

signals that `EVP_MD_CTX_new()` was not found in your header files, and is being considered a function that returns an integer, the default behavior in C.

And the error `example.c:(.text+0xc4): undefined reference to`EVP_MD_CTX_new'`

informs that `EVP_MD_CTX_new()` is not in your OpenSSL libraries.

Maybe your OpenSSL example is newer (or older) than the OpenSSL sample file that you're trying to compile.

Supposing that your example is newer than your libraries and header files, the usual solution would be to download the source files and recompile them in order to have an updated OpenSSL.

Another possibility is just the inverse: you have a newer OpenSSL and the example belongs to an older one. In that case you got to find a newer example.

So, you got to check the versions of all files involved.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, you definitely hit the nail on the head there. I compiled from source and all is now fine.